# Is there a way to copy_from_slice with a dynamic size?

Tags: arrays, rust, endianness

I am attempting to change an unknown section of a Vec into a 32 bit integer using from_le_bytes. I know that the size will be between 1 and 4 bytes, but that's all I know. Here is my attempt:

```
use std::u32;

fn main () {
    let my_vec : Vec<u8> = vec![5,1,2,3];
    let user_input = 1;
    let mut my_bytes : [u8;1] = Default::default();
    let val : u32 = match user_input {
        1 => {
            my_bytes.copy_from_slice(&my_vec[0..=0]);
            my_bytes[0]
        },
        2 => { 
            my_bytes.copy_from_slice(&my_vec[0..2]);
            u16::from_le_bytes(my_bytes)
        },
        4 => { 
            my_bytes.copy_from_slice(&my_vec[0..4]);
            u32::from_le_bytes(my_bytes);
        },
        _ => 0,
        
    };
    println!("{}",val);
}
```

The problem here is, `my_bytes` is static and I'm unaware of another type I could use in its place which might allow a dynamic size. How should this be corrected?

Comment: Actually you do not need the temporary: just write `u16::from_le_bytes(my_vec[0..2].try_into().unwrap())`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by Rodrigo:

> Actually you do not need the temporary: just write
> u16::from_le_bytes(my_vec[0..2].try_into().unwrap())

the following works:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main () {
    let my_vec : Vec<u8> = vec![5,1,2,1];
    let user_input = 4;
    let val : u32 = match user_input {
        1 => {
            my_vec[0].try_into().unwrap()
        },
        2 => { 
            u16::from_le_bytes(my_vec[0..2].try_into().unwrap()).try_into().unwrap()
        },
        4 => { 
            u32::from_le_bytes(my_vec[0..4].try_into().unwrap()).try_into().unwrap()
        },
        _ => 0,
        
    };
    println!("{}",val);
}
```

Comment: you don't need the last `.try_into().unwrap()` in each case, you can do `as u32`

Comment: @kmdreko Is `as u32` more efficient?

Comment: I don't know if `.try_into().unwrap()` would distill down to the same operations; I'd assume same or better. The TryFrom trait is for fallible conversions but `u8`/`u16` to `u32` is infallible so `.into()` would be more appropriate. Using `as` is available since you're converting primitives.